# Error 1064 (42000 in mysql code

Tags: mysql, sql

When i put my code in

```
CREATE TABLE EVENT (
    Event_ID SMALLINT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Event_Name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Event_Date DATE NOT NULL,
    Event_Route VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    Event_Location VARCHAR(60) NULL,
    Event_Cost DECIMAL(8,2) NOT NULL,
    Staff_ID SMALLINT FOREIGN KEY NOT NULL,
    Package_ID SMALLINT FOREIGN KEY NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Staff_ID FOREIGN KEY (Staff_ID) REFERENCES STAFF (Staff_ID),
    CONSTRAINT Package_ID FOREIGN KEY (Package_ID) REFERENCES PACKAGE  (Package_ID)
);
```

I get this error message below

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'FOREIGN KEY NOT NULL, Package_ID SMALLINT FOREIGN
>   KEY NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT Staff' at line 8

Answer (score 1):

I think the error is pretty clear.  You have key words in the middle of the definition of `Package_Id` and `Staff_Id` (`FOREIGN KEY`). These are not necessary, they are handled by the `constraint` definition:

```
CREATE TABLE EVENT (
    Event_ID SMALLINT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Event_Name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Event_Date DATE NOT NULL,
    Event_Route VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    Event_Location VARCHAR(60) NULL,
    Event_Cost DECIMAL(8,2) NOT NULL,
    Staff_ID SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    Package_ID SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Staff_ID FOREIGN KEY (Staff_ID) REFERENCES STAFF (Staff_ID),
    CONSTRAINT Package_ID FOREIGN KEY (Package_ID) REFERENCES PACKAGE  (Package_ID)
);
```

I would dissuade you from naming the table `Event` or even `Events`.  The name is not reserved, but it is a keyword in MySQL.

Comment: i'm a bit confused as to what you mean i have key words in the middle of definition

Comment: @Ruth Just to add a tiny bit of clarification, the column definitions `Staff_ID SMALLINT FOREIGN KEY NOT NULL` and `Package_ID SMALLINT FOREIGN KEY NOT NULL` would be considered erroneous as they shouldn't include [`FOREIGN KEY`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp) reference. It's only required with `CONSTRAINT`.

Comment: @Dhruv Saxena  I'm getting the same error with this code but i've changed it  `CREATE TABLE VOLUNTEER(
Volunteer_ID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
Volunteer_FirstName VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
Volunteer_LastName VARCHAR (40) NOT NULL,
Volunteer_Email VARCHAR(40) NULL,
FirstAid ENUM('Y','N') NOT NULL,
Station_ID SMALLINT NOT NULL,
Event_ID SMALLINT NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (Station_ID) REFERENCES STATION (Station_ID)
CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (Event_ID) REFERENCES EVENT (Event_ID)
);`

Comment: @Ruth To extend the previous comment, I reckon `FOREIGN KEY` keyword must be removed from both the column definitions, in case that's what is causing the problem at your end (looks like `FOREIGN KEY` is mistakenly left behind with `Staff_ID` in the answer)? Sorry if you've already tried with this too, but there's apparently no other reasonable way for the said syntax error to still creep in. @GordonLinoff, Sir, I apologise for intrusion and being nit-picky. Would have cleansed the typo, though the edit queue is full at the moment.